# RabbitMQ consumer thread pool increases with every request

Tags: java, multithreading, rabbitmq

I've developed a Java 7 application with RabbitMQ 3.6.6 (AMQP Client 4.0.2). My consumer class extends `DefaultConsumer`. Every request that I send via the RabbitMQ Management console starts a new thread (*pool-2-thread-n*) according to the log:

```
info: pool-2-thread-10 - NumberConsumer - Number request
info: pool-2-thread-11 - NumberConsumer - Number request
info: pool-2-thread-12 - NumberConsumer - Number request
info: pool-2-thread-13 - NumberConsumer - Number request
info: pool-2-thread-14 - NumberConsumer - Number request
info: pool-2-thread-15 - NumberConsumer - Number request
info: pool-2-thread-16 - NumberConsumer - Number request
info: pool-2-thread-17 - NumberConsumer - Number request
info: pool-2-thread-18 - NumberConsumer - Number request
info: pool-2-thread-19 - NumberConsumer - Number request
```

My consumer class:

```
public class NumberConsumer extends DefaultConsumer
{
   private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger( NumberConsumer.class );

   public NumberConsumer(final Channel channel)
   {
      super( channel );
   }


   @Override
   public void handleDelivery(final String consumerTag, final Envelope envelope,
         final AMQP.BasicProperties properties, final byte[] body)
      throws IOException
   {
      final String request = new String( body, "UTF-8" );
      NumberConsumer.LOG.info( "Number request" );

      // ... do work and publish response ...
   }
}
```

Is this behavior expected?
I'm quite sure that every thread is closed when it's done handling its request but why isn't their number limited? Can this be configured?

Comment: To make a sophisticated argument, one would have to know how the Pool is configured exactly. It *could* be normal behavior. BTW: The number n in "pool-x-thread-n" does not say there are n Threads (concurrently). The executing Thread is the nth that has been created by that thread factory.

Comment: You didn't provide your own ExecutorService, did you?

Comment: No, I didn't. Just saw that in the documentation, `ConnectionFactory` has multiple `newConnection(..)` methods which allow you to set a `ExecutorService`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AMQP Java client has its own thread pool for consumers in the `ConnectionFactory`. If this shall not be used you have to supply an own `ExecutorService` as a parameter for the `newConnection(..)` method.